# Can't save data to MVC (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I can't save my data from textfield to MVC.

When I enter text and click on the button, the data is not added.

how can i fix it?

I delete **viewDidLoad()** with **table.delegate = self, table.dataSource = self** from this Question.

**This is the ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Text: UITextField!

    var model = ViewModel()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.persons?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let person = model.persons?[indexPath.row]
        cell.Name?.text = person?.name
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
        model.input = sender.text
    }

    @IBAction func Add(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let name = model.input, name.count > 0 {
            let person = Person()
            person.name = name
            model.addPerson(person)
            model.input = nil
        }
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class ViewModel {
    var persons: [Person]?
    var input: String?

    func addPerson(_ person: Person) {
        if persons == nil { persons = [] }
        persons?.append(person)
    }
}
class Person {
    var name: String?
}
```

Comment: Did you add breakpoints to your add method? It looks like if it enters that code block your code should work...

Comment: @ridvankucuk I don't add breakpoints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try this
```

//    func textFieldEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
//        model.input = sender.text
//    }

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    model.input = textField.text
}


@IBAction func Add(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    if let name = model.input, name.count > 0 {
        let person = Person()
        person.name = name
        model.addPerson(person)
        model.input = nil
    }
    table.reloadData()
}
```